# HTML: how to add anchor tag without effecting visual display?

Tags: html

I want to add an HTML anchor tag to a page but in a way that doesn't effect the layout or formatting. When using an `<a>` or `<p>` or `<div>`, etc., some vertical white space is introduced.

Is there a way to include an anchor such that it doesn't effect the visual display of the page?

Assume that I don't want to include this anchor inside an already existing paragraph or other element, and that I want to simply introduce the anchor at will anywhere in the page without changing the page's display.

UPDATE 1

This is a simple example. Inserting `anchor1` below introduces vertical space. Is there a way to simply insert an anchor willy nilly without effecting visual layout? The anchor will be used as a link to jump to a specific location on a page.

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p id="anchor1"></p>
<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what's going without seeing actual layout. Can you show the demo before and after adding anchor?

Comment: Check the css of the page.

Comment: What do mean by “anchor tag”? A link, or a potential destination for links? What have you tried, and exactly how does it disturb visual presentation?

Comment: There are multiple answers/tips here, but the most straightforward is: Why don't you just add the id to the next paragraph instead of adding an empty one?

Comment: For example, what if the paragraph is very long and I want to insert a link in the middle of it?

Comment: If you don't want to attach it to an existing element, do it like Felix describes in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't add the ID to an existing element, use an actual [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> The HTML `<a>` Element (or the HTML Anchor Element) defines a hyperlink, the named target destination for a hyperlink, or both.

HTML4:

```
<a name="anchor1"></a>
```

HTML5:

```
<a id="anchor1"></a>
```

Comment: Adding an `a` element between `p` elements affects rendering (by preventing collapse of vertical margins), and the edited question shows two `p` elements and an added empty `p` element between them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I forgot about the margins, however, they don't seem to affect the collapsing: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz7Rj/. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FelixKling, indeed it seems that browsers do not let an element with empty content prevent vertical margins from collapsing. But this is illogical and not guaranteed in CSS specs, AFAICS. In logical use, an element with empty content (when the content model allows some content) is a placeholder for content to be inserted, rather than a completely ignorable element.